# NPC's died, need them back

Tags: terraria-mobile

In hardmode, all my npcs died and I've waited 6 real days for them to come back.

They died during a blood moon to a [**World Feeder**](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/World_Feeder). I'm only getting the guides settlement message. All my rooms are good for them to move into as well.

How can I make sure they come back and respawn? This is on the IOS/Tablet version.

Comment: When you go into the room viewer (where you have the button to check if something is a valid room) do you see their banners? if so try moving away from the rooms (ie. going underground a far way) and when you get back they should be in there

Comment: This isn't much of a question. Yout state at the end... "I'm hoping I can get them back" So your not actually ASKING us for help...

Answer (score 3):

All you can do is wait for them to return, or spawn them in with programs such as [**TEdit**]

Make sure your buildings fit the following requirements for housing.

```
Excluding ceiling, floor and walls | Including ceiling, floor and walls  
------------------------------------------------------------------------
6 blocks wide x 6 blocks high      | 8 blocks wide x 8 blocks high  
7 blocks wide x 5 blocks high      | 9 blocks wide x 7 blocks high  
8 blocks wide x 4 blocks high      | 10 blocks wide x 6 blocks high  
10 blocks wide x 3 blocks high     | 12 blocks wide x 5 blocks high
```

That information, and more can be found on the [**wiki**](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Home) page.

Comment: Why the downvote? I can't exactly help due to the low quality of the question...

Comment: Alright then... I added some more info to it deeming it more "reliable"

Comment: @aytimothy No, contains all information about homes. Including that stuff I added.

Comment: Hangon.. I thought that was the main page. Nevermind.